# Using Gmail API with PHP: How to make a CLI app work in the browser?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, gmail-api

I'm testing the Gmail API.

So far, I'm using the [PHP client example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples), and selected my environment as "desktop", because "other" is not available an s website environment wouldn't work.

It won't work because when I access the php file using a browser, I get:

Open the following link in your browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=35587452231052-k48bjsgefmnsbd654shdbf026q1un.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly&prompt=select_account%20consent Enter verification code:

And there's no place to actually ***type*** the verification code after the verification.

When I access it from the terminal I just paste the verification code and that's it.

This may be a silly question, but how do I make it work in a page?

### Here's my file:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Gmail Access');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . 'credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code:';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
.........
```

Everything that I add to the file appears in the CLI, but I can't move on from there and actually make it work in the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the [OAuth Flow for Web applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). There is a difference in the credentials object, and the token would be stored in the session, meaning you don't have to copy and paste it into a terminal.

#### Example code:

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php

---

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/README.md#authentication-with-oauth

Answer (score 0):

You are contorting the 'Web flow' with the 'Command line flow'.  While there is some overlap, ultimatly, they use different functionality to receive the authorization code.

Obviously, using `fgets(STDIN)` in web path isn't going to work.  You need to follow the example previously stated: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php to use redirects and get the code from `$_GET` globals.